# 'Per' vs 'by' - as in 'interactions by/per post'

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

I'm attempting to get a title for a list of interactions made on posts by users.

"Interactions by/per post".
Are by and per interchangeable? Is one more formal than the other?

I feel that *by* might be easily misunderstood as interactions made by the posts itself instead of interactions with the posts by users. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: Interactions via post or snail-mail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Interactions per post": the average number of interactions that happen on a post.

"Interactions by post": A list of interactions sorted by post. (Ignoring the possibility that *post* could be mistaken for *mail*)